# Can't access other user's Azure subscription with Visual Studio

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013

I was given "contributor" status on a co-worker's Azure subscription in order to collaborate on a project. I verified I have access to the dashboard at portal.azure.com.

When I connect my Visual Studio 2013 to Azure (via server explorer), I can only see my own subscription, and there is only the option to connect with a different Microsoft account.

Is there a specific way/role I need to be added to the co-workers Azure account in order to help Visual Studio along?

Comment: Do you use the same account to access both subscriptions?

Comment: Alternatively you can ask the owner to upload a management certificate, and send it over to you, so that you can access in Visual Studio through certificate rather than Live ID.

Comment: @BrendanGreen same account. "Manage Microsoft Azure Subscriptions" has only my own subscription listed.

Comment: @ShaunXu: RBAC is much more secure than distributing certificates or publish profiles.  I've run into this same issue.

Comment: @BenV Agree. I ran into the same issue for one of my subscription and I changed to use cert. If you don't want to use cert I think you've to contact azure support.